# Wrong products after filtering attribute in layered navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, layered-navigation

I have a problem i try to solve for a while but i can find the exact issue.

The problem: after i filter a bulb type like H7, i also get products from another bulb type like HB4 so people can be confused what to order now.

I tried all possible combinations of attribute, refreshing cache, reindex but the wrong products still show up.(bulb type only for simple products, these simple products are used in bundle products.)

Has anyone has seen this issue before and have a solution for this?

this is a [link](http://www.hilox.eu/auto-motor-verlichting/h7) for the issue

I use magento 1.9.4.2

Comment: what is the sku of this product HB4

Comment: The sku is LEM.HB4, i tried a dynamic and fixed sku. both results stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

After some testing and searching i found the real problem it was a wrong setting. When adding bundle products you can set input type. When selected multiple select or radio buttons with multiple simple products it doesnt work.

You must select input type checkbox and then set these product as default.